# Почему не срабатывает метод?

Tags: java, android

Мне нужно открывать клавиатуру автоматически когда юзер открывает активити, вот есть для этого такой метод

```
public static void openKeyBoard(Context context, View view) {
    Log.e("!!!!!!!!!!", "!!!!!!!!!!!! 2");

    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager =
            (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(
            view.getApplicationWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
}
```

Когда я вызываю этот метод по нажатию на кнопку все открывается и `Log` внутри этой функции тоже отпечатывается, но когда я вызываю этот метод из `onCreate()` то `Log` отпечатывается, но больше ничего не происходит.

То есть сама функция вызывается, но метод не срабатывает, а когда нажимаю на кнопку к которой привязан этот метод то открывается...

Я подумал, может проблема в том, что я передаю в этот метод `View` элемент который еще не успевает создаться и решил прикрепить вызов этого метода после того как `View` будет создан, вот так

```
final LinearLayout registrationLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.registrationLinearLayout);
    registrationLinearLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            UtilClass.openKeyBoard(context, registrationLinearLayout);
        }
    });
```

Но все равно, `Log` срабатывает, метод вызывается, но ничего не происходит...

Что делаю не так?

Comment: А если в onResume вызвать?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб почитал побольше об этом и так понял, что это стандартная проблема если хочется реализовать автоматический подьем клавиатуры. Нашел решение, опубликовал ниже...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В итоге вот так решил

```
public static void openKeyBoard(final View view) {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            view.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN , 0, 0, 0));
            view.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_UP , 0, 0, 0));
        }
    }, 200);
}
```

Как `view` я передаю `EditText`

Comment: Вопрос не по теме. Что делает метод `dispatchTouchEvent`? Для чего он нужен?

Comment: @MansurNashaev насколько я понимаю, в этом методе происходит имитация нажатия на `EditText` с задержкой 200 мс. Следуя из названия этот метод отправляет сигнал о нажатии

Comment: Благодарю за ответ.